# Highcharts: yAxis.height does not scale drawable area, causing graph to go off the chart

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 spline charts that I want to compare on a singe graph.  The first should take up the top 25% of the plot area and the second should take up the bottom 75% of the plot area.  To achieve this, I tried the following:

```
"yAxis": [{
    "height": "25%",
    "id": "blue",
    "labels": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "min": 267.15,
    "max": 289.15,
    "index": 0
  },{
    "id": "red",
    "height":"75%",
    "top": "25%",
    "min": 265,
    "max": 290,
    "plotLines": [{
      "color": "#fff8df",
      "value": 285.15
    }, {
      "color": "#fff8df",
      "value": 279.15
    }, {
      "color": "#c5eded",
      "value": 273.15
    }],
    "index": 1
  }],
```

The problem with this is that I have a min/max set (the graph is showing temperatures and we only care about a certain range).  Because of these combined things, the graph is drawing right over the xAxis and outside of the expected plot area.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/06f9huam/

What I would like to see is the red line to be cut off if it goes below 265, just like it gets cut off when it goes over 290.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cut the unnecessary parts of lines by using `clip-path` attribute, example:

```
    chart: {
        animation: false,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                const series1 = this.series[0];
                const series2 = this.series[1];

                const clipRect1 = this.renderer.clipRect(
                    series1.yAxis.left - series1.group.translateX,
                    series1.yAxis.top - series1.group.translateY,
                    series1.yAxis.width,
                    series1.yAxis.height
                );

                const clipRect2 = this.renderer.clipRect(
                    series2.yAxis.left - series2.group.translateX,
                    series2.yAxis.top - series2.group.translateY,
                    series2.yAxis.width,
                    series2.yAxis.height
                );

                series1.graph.clip(clipRect1);
                series2.graph.clip(clipRect2);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15e3g78w/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#clipRect

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#clip